# How to map and log exceptions but still have SpringBoot render the JSON response?

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I want a global exception handler that

a) maps certain exceptions to HTTP response codes, maybe by translating e.g. `NoSuchElementException` to `ResponseStatusException`

b) adds logging depending on the exception, e.g. NullPointerException gets more verbose logging
than NoSuchElementExceptions

c) uses the SpringBoot JSON error response i.e. `{ timestamp: ..., status: ..., error: ... }`

I read

- https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring and
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

but most approaches, like `@ExceptionHandler` want me to provide the HTTP response body. I want to use the original SpringBoot JSON error message though which is probably made by the `DefaultErrorAttributes` class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that the obvious solution with `@ExceptionHandler` does indeed work but I had to add `server.error.message: always` to get the exception message into the response as well!
(the default is ok as it can contain sensitive information!)

Apart from that it looks like:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandlers {

   @ExceptionHandler
   fun handleAllErrors(e: Throwable, response: HttpServletResponse) {
      ...
      response.sendError(status, message)
   }
}
```